# Ubuntu 18.04 Openstack Deployment - 'hook failed: "install"'

Tags: 18.04, juju, maas, openstack, cloud

I was trying to deploy Openstack using Juju and MaaS.

I get the error

```
hook failed: "install"
```

[image: CLI screenshot]

After debugging I find this error:
[Debug file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo28x.png)

Any help?

Comment: You''ll need to look in the logs to see what went wrong. Ssh into the machine and look in `/var/log/juju/unit-glance-1.log` or use `juju debug-log --include glance/1`.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).